# Create CAD model of a 3D trajectory in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, curve

I have an array `x` of 3D positions in Matlab. I would need to convert this trajectory into a CAD model (for simulation on another software that need 3D CAD files for trajectories).

How can I convert a 3D Matlab trajectory into a 3D file (STEP, IGES, etc.)?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/smlink/index.html#custom-cad-export see the last menu item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file exchange function [Nurbs2IGES](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12087-nurbs2iges) that might do the trick for you as well as an [igesout](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14470-igesout) function.

Also, depending on the CAD software you are trying to use, many such as Solidworks allow you to import a text file of points which can then be connected in the CAD software itself. [Here](http://grabcad.com/questions/tutorial-how-to-import-points-to-solidworks-from-a-text-file) is a related tutorial for Solidworks.

Comment: Your tutorial for connecting points imported in Solidworks is perfect. Thanks!